# add information to input when AJAX returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I submit a form via AJAX and it returns null, I want to append a text message below the original input box, and when I resubmit with a valid value(which means the AJAX call returns what I want), delete this message.

How can I do this? Thank you so much!!

I tried something like this in my AJAX call:

```
success: function(data){
      if(data.Status === "SUCCESS"){
                //deal with the data
            }else{
                //NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE
            }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using  `.insertAfter()`?

Comment: `.hide()` , `.show()` , `.toggle()` you can use  these things for what you wanted

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can delete msg in "SUCCESS", add msg delete it in else case.
Add function: append() appendTo() insertAfter()
delete function: remove() empty()
You can select it in you case.